# How to freeze a player at an unknown location, while letting them look around

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to freeze a player, but I need them to be able to look around at the same time and be able to freeze them at an unknown location that the command block cannot just guess. I need something that is minimally glitchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple to do, yet there aren't any tutorials (that I've seen) out there on how to do this. So it's a single command and can be influenced even further so when you add tags. It is as follows:

```
/execute @p[name=NAME] ~ ~ ~ /teleport @p ~ ~ ~
```

This will be put in a repeating command block.

You have to change NAME to the player name or just change it to @a. Do not change the second @p. Make sure your next to the command block so you can break the command block when you get stuck. Use McEdit to break the command block if you accidentally set it off ;) . Good luck.

**Comment by [SkylinerW](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/128137/skylinerw)**

So I admit I have not debugged this method and was actually testing this on a server with only me on it. I came across this method by chance. According to SkylinerW if a player had died (while the first selector was the @a selector) then the remaining alive player would be teleported directly to the dead player's body. His comment included a method to fix this:

> "Do not change the second @p" - If you change the initial selector to @a, then you must change the second to @a[c=1].

Full credits to the fix go to [SkylinerW](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/128137/skylinerw), and you can read the rest of his comment below.

Comment: "Do not change the second @p" - If you change the initial selector to `@a`, then you must change the second to `@a[c=1]`. Only the `@a` selector can target dead players, so if the player were to die while the second selector used `@p`, the dead player would instead be teleporting the nearest-living player, causing conflicts with the mechanism.